# how to draw X Y Z 3D animation in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My ArrayList has X Y Z (matrix)

I want to draw X y Z  in WPF and have a 3D animation when drawing.

How can I make a 3D environment in a WPF application?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Wpf3DPrimer.aspx
Also I would suggest to go through:
http://www.wpftutorial.net/IntroductionTo3D.html
and
http://www.kindohm.com/technical/wpf3dtutorial.htm

I hope you can find everything you need in there..

Cheers,
Gianluca.